# Compare the structure of two "brother" SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison, schema

To compare a base table with its archive table (conventionally, `arc_` + the base table name), I've written the following to show the number of columns in both tables, the columns which exist on one side but not on the other, and the columns which are different between both sides:

```
DECLARE @base_tbl varchar(20) = 'appointments'

DECLARE @arch_tbl varchar(20) = 'arc_' + @base_tbl
DECLARE @schema varchar(35) = 'some'

-- Count in base table.
SELECT @base_tbl, COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @base_tbl AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema

-- Count in archive table.
SELECT @arch_tbl, COUNT(*)
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @arch_tbl AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema

-- Columns only in the base or in the archive table.
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, IS_NULLABLE
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (@base_tbl, @arch_tbl) AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
  AND COLUMN_NAME IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM
      (
          SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
          FROM information_schema.columns
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = @base_tbl AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
              UNION
          SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
          FROM information_schema.columns
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = @arch_tbl AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
      ) u
      GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
      HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME

-- Differences.
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION, IS_NULLABLE
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME IN (@base_tbl, @arch_tbl) AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
  AND COLUMN_NAME IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_NAME FROM
      (
          SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION
          FROM information_schema.columns
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = @base_tbl AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
              UNION
          SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, NUMERIC_PRECISION
          FROM information_schema.columns
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = @arch_tbl AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @schema
      ) v
GROUP BY COLUMN_NAME
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
```

I'm wondering whether this is improvable, for readability or better output support. WDYT?

Comment: This is probable better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did not know about that. Will certainly use it!  Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't `FULL JOIN` do all this?

```
SELECT c1.COLUMN_NAME, c1.DATA_TYPE, c2.COLUMN_NAME, c2.DATA_TYPE
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM information_schema.columns c1
    WHERE c1.TABLE_NAME = 'xxx' AND c1.table_schema = 'xxx'
) c1
FULL JOIN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM information_schema.columns c2
    WHERE c2.TABLE_NAME = 'yyy' AND c2.table_schema = 'yyy'
) c2
ON c1.COLUMN_NAME = c2.COLUMN_NAME
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN c1.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL OR c2.COLUMN_NAME IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    ISNULL(c1.COLUMN_NAME, c2.COLUMN_NAME)
```

Comment: To iterate of a couple of well-known tables (in my app -- let's say "t1", "t2" and "t3"), what should I do?  Encapsulate the above as a stored proc?  Or is there a way to make a "for" loop?

Comment: By the way, very smart output, which easily allows to select columns based on different criterias (the ones which have a type difference, or a length difference, etc.). Much better than what I had!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: _"couple of well-known tables"_ - you want to compare more than two tables at once or you want to compare sequentially pares of tables?

Comment: The latest (compare t1 against arc_t1 followed by the comparison of t2 against arc_t2 and so on, all in one "report").

Comment: Declare `@table`, put pairs of table names to compare there  and read serially in while loop. Declare `@report` table, put each iteration result (output of full join) into it.